# "The RPC server is unavailable"

Tags: windows-vista, rpc, perfmon

this is driving me crazy.
I have 2 testing machine, one XP, and one Vista.
I am running the same commands on both.
These commands include creating a logman counter ( like a perfmon with command prompt), starting these counters, then stopping them, and then deleting them.

The problem is this:
On XP they work perfectly, I am getting all the statistics, and it works always.
On Vista, they work on the first time, but then I always get the error back, "The RPC server is unavailable."

This happens when I try to start the counter, not when i create it.

When I try to check the RPC server, it is running.

And to make it even more confusing, the counters are running on the local machine.
(so for the XP, they run on the XP, and for the Vista, they are running on the Vista.)
So an even weirder question is, why is it using RPC in the first place?

Did anyone meet this error ever before please?
I am really stuck.

I did a lot of research, and it seems to be common. Most solutions ( that according to the Original Posters do not work) are always to check if the service is running.

P.S. 
This also replicates itself when I add counters manually, so even through perfmon.
It seems that it works, then something goes wrong and it does not want to work again, without a restart of the machine.

P.P.S The services.msc also does not let me restart the RPC service, not even as admin.

Comment: Run the service Secure Socket tunneling protocol service

Answer (score 1):

[Why do I get 'The RPC Server is Unavailable' messages?](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-i-get-the-rpc-server-is-unavailable-messages.html)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/884564

Comment: I tried what the first site says, and it is still for nothing
1) I tried using the IP to refer to the machine, and
2) I checked that all relevant services are running.

As for the second link, I checked it too, and it was for nothing.
Also, that error is reported to be on XP, while for me XP works fine, while the Vista machine is what screws up.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the UAC is the problem.

Try disabling UAC (go to "Control Panel - User Accounts" and click "Turn User Account Control on or off").