# Process-crash with the message "RPC server is unavailable" on opening a save file dialog?

Tags: c++, qt, windows-7

On Windows 7 64-bit, I use Qt 4.5.3 to call QFileDialog::getSaveFileName. Immediately on calling this function, my process crashes with the message "The RPC server is unavailable".

I found this, but it doesn't solve my problem:
["The RPC server is unavailable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063096/the-rpc-server-is-unavailable)

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you call getSaveFileName? What are the arguments you're giving? If you don't set the dir, could you try something like the root of a drive, or a temp directory and see if the problem persists?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm having exactly the same problem, but with Qt 4.7.0. Windows 7, 64-bit.
Calling QFileDialog::getOpenFileName or QFileDialog::getSaveFileName crash my process with the following message: "First-chance exception at 0x7486b9bc in SoundManager.exe: 0x000006BA: The RPC server is unavailable."

The RPC Server is running in my services list.

The only way that i found (not clean) to bypass this bug is to add the Win32 exception 0x6BA in the exception list of Visual Studio (CTRL+ALT+E) and disable it. The Exception is not thrown and my program still work after a call of these functions. I have to do this manipulation on each computer that we are using for software development.

All Windows 7 64 bit here are having the same behavior.

Comment: Real answer from Pieter (sadly deleted): *Visual Studio was breaking on all exceptions, I mistook it for a crash.*  A 'first chance exception' is not a real one until nobody catches it.  Use the Debug + Exceptions dialog to get rid of the fake ones.

Comment: What exception am I looking for? The RPC server is unavailable is not in the list of exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

The combination of these 2 posts helped me understand the problem and solution:

[How to: Break When an Exception is Thrown (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx)

[How to make visual studio break only on unhandled exceptions? (stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183099/how-to-make-visual-studio-break-only-on-unhandled-exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking Debug->Exceptions->Win32_Exceptions helped me.