# Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library Exception in c#

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++

I am using a fingerprint capture device in my c# application, this device has c# wrapper class for a c++ SDK dll. 
Sometimes i get a c++ exception message (see image) and then the application close, the problem is that I can't catch this exception and can't keep application running after this exception.
 The Question is: How Can I Catch This Exception in C#?[image]

Comment: maybe you can force Visual Studio to break if this exception occurs ([Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183099/how-to-make-visual-studio-break-only-on-unhandled-exceptions)) ... maybe you will find invalid parameters in dll-function calls....

Answer (score 1):

> How Can I Catch This Exception in C#?

You cannot. An unmanaged C++ exception cannot be caught by managed code. You need to catch unmanaged exceptions in unmanaged code. You cannot let unmanaged exceptions propagate outside the unmanaged module.

However, the error dialog suggests that you have a more serious problem. One that cannot be dealt with simply by catching an exception. You will need to work out why your program is terminating the runtime in this catastrophic way, and stop that happening. That error dialog suggests that your [program is calling `abort()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177152/what-is-the-cause-of-this-application-has-requested-the-runtime-to-terminate-it), which is terminal.

In other words you need to prevent this error from happening in the first place, rather than attempting to recover from it. This is not an error that you can hope to recover from.