# How can I set up VS2015 to throw errors when I mess up my JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

When going through a code review, my technical lead picked up a few missing semicolons in my JavaScript when he went into debug. Visual Studio actually threw these exceptions up, and I was wondering where the option to turn that on was.

I've searched '[JavaScript Debugging in Visual Studio 20(15|13)](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=JavaScript%20Debugging%20in%20Visual%20Studio%2020(15%7C13))', but it seems like there aren't any simple settings to enable.

Wondering the most efficient way to turn on JavaScript debugging in visual studio for *all* projects without having to add something each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have **Just My Code** Enabled by going into Tools-->Options-->Debugger-->General--> Enable Just My Code. This will change your Debug--> Windows --> Exceptions Settings Dialog Box to show a CheckBox for JavaScript RunTime Exceptions.

Javascript RunTime Exceptions:
[image]

See this answer for previous versions of [Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11183553/855916)

Comment: Hmm... Enable Just My Code is checked, but the 'Exception Settings' only have on/off- no second box for user unhandled.

Comment: Your right, the checkbox is Javascript runtime exceptions... updated original post. And added an image.

Comment: This was it, also had to run it in IE to get it to throw the errors. Not sure if that means that IE is the actual checker here.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want [JSLint](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ede12aa8-0f80-4e6f-b15c-7a8b3499370e)

You can also look into using TypeScript which is a superset of javascript and allows you to strongly type your javascript.