# c# Handling exception for a wrong SQL query

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have seen similar questions regarding this topic which were asked earlier but couldn't find a solution for the above problem. I have an add-on programmed in c# for SAP B1. User has to enter some database column names to a UDT. Then my function run a query and fetch the data. But in case of user entering wrong column name to the table, I should have a proper error handling to catch this error and prevent the add-on from crashing. My code is given below.

```
try
{
 sqlString = "select " + databaseFieldName[increase] + " from OITM where ItemCode= '" + itemCode + "'";
 mRsitemCode.DoQuery(sqlString);
}
catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
{
 SBO_Application.MessageBox(ex.ToString(), 1, "Ok");
}
catch (Exception b)
{
  //string error;
  SBO_Application.MessageBox(b.ToString(), 1, "Ok");
}
```

But it doesn't run into any of my catch blocks. The error is given below.

> An exception (first chance) of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in
>   Item_Variation.dll.
>
> Additional information: 1). [Microsoft] [SQL Server Native Client
>   10.0] [SQL Server] Invalid column name 'WhsCode'.
>
> 2). [Microsoft] [SQL Server Native Client 10.0] [SQL Server] Statement
>   (s) Could not be prepared.
>
> If a handler is available for this exception, the program may continue
>   to run safely.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that: 1. the exception actually occurs in the shown line and not somewhere else? 2. the line in exception handler isn't actually being executed? Maybe simply the message box is not shown? Can you stop in the line with the debugger?

Comment: @KubaWyrostek : I tried to debug and it stoped at line `mRsitemCode.DoQuery(sqlString);` and the error messaged popped up(crashed). It didn't run into the catch block.

Comment: Do you have your settings configured to break on exceptions. I am not sure this is the cause of the problem, but might be something

Comment: @ChrisBint No Idea. How can I do it VS2010? Forgive me I'm just an intern :(

Comment: From Debug/Exceptions menu. You can simply select it not to break on any exception, but again, not sure if this is your problem or not. Might be worth trying.

Comment: It does sound a lot like you have "break on first-chance exceptions" enabled. How you check it depends on VS version, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183099/how-to-make-visual-studio-break-only-on-unhandled-exceptions

Comment: @ChrisBint Thanks a lot that was the problem. Now it works fine. Can you post it as an answer. Then I can mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Visual Studio is configured to break on exceptions. If you use the Debug/Exceptions menu to select which errors you would like to break on, rather than let your code continue, you can do so.